# How can i hide a class

Tags: css

I'm using a CSS layout on both html page.

I want to use the same style except I want to hide/disable other `classes` made for it for the second html page and still use the others on the first html page.

Situation:

`class="firstClass"` has the fonts and style I wanted with it but has other `classes` and styles that shows when I use that `class`.

I tried getting the other classes by adding a secondClass on the same level of the first class, then did this:

```
.firstClass .secondClass, .dontWant1 .dontWant2 {
    display:none;
}
```

Problem is it also hides on the first html.

Comment: Please clarify your situation and desired result. Show the HTML

Comment: .secondClass, .dontWant1 .dontWant2 {
    display:none;
} Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, what help do you want from our side ?

Comment: @Deckerz, it hides everything if I do your suggestion. I tried that already.

Comment: @kishanradadiya, Is there a way I can hide the other classes (.dontWant1, .dontWant2) without affecting the .firstClass who makes those classes visible.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I'll try to show HTML in awhile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple classes on one element. That said, you add classes on one page that you dont add on the other page, to show elements on page 1 and hide them on page 2.

You can have that one class `show` or `dontshow` to define what elements are visible.

Then you add a class to define your styles.

HTML/CSS:

```css
.greenbox {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.redbox {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}


.show {
  display: block;
}
.dontshow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="greenbox">
  
  <div class="show">
    <div class="redbox">
      <!-- red box visible -->
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="dontshow">
    <div class="redbox">
      <!-- red box not visible -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dontshow redbox">
      <!-- red box not visible -->
      <!-- exactly the same outcome as the above without the wrapping div -->
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: 
html:

```
<div class="main">
     content goes here.
</div>

<div class="main active">
    content goes here.
</div>
```

css:

```
.main {
 background-color:yellow;
 display:none;
}

.active {
  display:block; OR display:block !important;
}
```